# how to use Observers design pattern in two different computer in same program

Tags: c#, user-interface, design-patterns, observer-pattern, multitasking

I'm going to code a program (I'm learning .net c#) that update the mysql database table(think table name is bookTbl), many computers can simultaneously run this program in same time, think there is three computers (A,B,C) running on this program, they are interconnected with a network. if computer A update the database table bookTbl, it must suddenly notify the other computer B and C. so I thought about the Observers design pattern but I can't think how to do it. I am new to software design patters. I googled and found some sources, all the things are console based. please can anyone give me a good diagram to figure out this or any web link or tutorials ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of options:

- watch the database for changes regularly by each program
- use job on server that would watch the db and then notify you programs
- use a centralized point (service) that would receive a message once there is an update and then broadcast it to other computers

Given that you have more processes/computers involved I would read something about service oriented architecture and inter process communication also. Software design patterns are about how the code is structured within your program.

You could also take a look at http://particular.net/nservicebus but this may be overkill for what you want.